# How can I avoid using server-side sessions for authentication in a Java webapp?

Tags: session, authentication, jakarta-ee, web-applications, stateless

I'd like to secure access to resources in my web application, so I authenticate my users using the standard mechanisms and use server-side sessions to preserve the authenticated state.

I'd like to deploy across multiple systems in a load balanced configuration, but I don't want to start synchronising session state across my infrastructure. Are there ways (using either spec-driven facilities in Java EE or commonly available libs like Spring Security) of preserving the authentication state of a user without server-side sessions, for example by pushing the required state back out to the client? If so, are there additional risks I need to be aware of?

---

Update - I am using declarative security as per Java EE webapp specs and authenticating via an LDAP repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a framework solution, but the following does work:

After the user successfully logged in you create a secured token and set it's value as a cookie. The token contains all information required (user ID, creation time, etc.) and is encrypted using some algorithm. So all nodes in your cluster can read the token, decrypt it and identify the user. Then you create a `ServletFilter` intercepting all requests, examining the token and set corresponding user credentials for e.g. `ServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` by using an `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

One way to solve the problem. But you must take care, self-made security must be well-thought-out.

Answer (score 1):

You can store some kind of token in a cookie after authentication, and manage session attributes yourself. E.g., have a database table whose primary key is the authentication token and stores user session data... Don't forget to implement a job to clean inactive "sessions".

As for what you should be aware of, keep in mind that cookies are something easy to access, steal, delete, disable, etc. The authentication token should be something strong and verifiable (hash a combination of the user ip + browser + rotating salt + some other things you can check for).

It is also wise to divide user authentications in two levels. "Has the cookie" and "just validated the cookie"... Let's say that "has the cookie" is a state that can be there for half an hour (or maybe more) which allows the user to navigate the site. "Just validated" state is for important operations, and should require the user to enter it's credentials again. The timeout for this "just validated state" shouldn't be much longer than a couple of minutes.

Keep in mind that I'm assuming that your site is not holding really sensitive data. For those situations I would recommend something such as two-way SSL authentication with external tokens or security cards plus rotating token devices plus biometrics authentication :D:D:D... I guess you see my point.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open id server to authentication thus separating your authentication and application logic.

Comment: I think I still have the same problem. (I'm using LDAP auth at the moment) When the user tries to access a protected resource they are sent to a login form. They log in, and then (if successful) are sent on to the resource. But I think a session ID is then used to 'remember' that the user is logged on, requiring the session data to be stored on the server. How can I avoid storing the session data on the server but still remember the user's authentication state?